# Suspicious voting activity patterns

Tags: support, voting, flags, abuse

Suspicious voting activity: is there a list / FAQ of currently known patterns?

I'm not asking about how the current automatic system works, but rather what I have to be on the lookout for when reviewing / flagging. The automatic system most probably includes features such as analyzing the voting graph (PageRank algorithm would probably be a good fit here), comparing IP addresses for suspected sock puppets, tracing proxies to the same organization, etc. - techniques not available to me.

Comment: "Clobber you with downvotes"? You have a net total of -6 across seven questions. If you add up all your up and down votes, you're fairly positive. Downvotes aren't about whether the quality of your post is bad; they're about whether the *subject* of your post is bad.

Comment: @NicolBolas, the reason I'm having a positive rate is precisely because I've looked at how META works and refrain from asking, unless I am absolutely sure. In any case, I'm taking down that update. It was a momentary weakness.

Comment: No sweat, [this is also how Meta works](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: Well, if you see something odd like an _extremely_ poorly written post getting an unjustified number of votes, that's typically worth a flag - or other patterns that just don't seem 'quite right'. You'd also be amazed at how often people accidentally tell on themselves, it happens quite a bit. You're bound to see it during the course of reviewing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to be on the lookout for anything; the system does it for you.

Focus on flagging [low quality posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts?s=1&pagesize=15&filter=day) instead :)

Note: Unless you become an SE dev, nobody will *ever* tell you the exact patterns the vote fraud script catches. It's top secret to prevent people from circumventing it.

Comment: >Focus on flagging low quality posts instead :) - Is it a hint? By the way, automatically detected 'low quality posts' are mostly fine. I've stopped reviewing them - concentrating rather on first questions / answers and on late answers.

Comment: @malenkiy_scot: Single-line answers/link-only answers deserve downvotes and sometimes a flag. At least downvote them, no need to flag (certain mods decline those, certain mods don't)

Comment: I can't downvote an answer unless I am a (relative) expert in the subject matter. In areas where I am a relative expert, I've seen many an excellent one-line answer (mostly a code snippet that solves the problem better than many words). What I am saying is that it is simply not worth my time to prowl through all those presumably 'low quality' answers when I can't judge them on merits in most cases.

Comment: @malenkiy_scot: A code snippet is bad no matter what. It solves the OP's immediate problem, but it doesn't really help other visitors. And nobody _learns_ from it. That's sort of against the StackExchange motto/whatever--we want to make the Internet Better. We _do not_ want to degrade into one of those quick-fix forums. All posts should carry some good explanation. Unfortunately, the size of SO has lead to such posts becoming rampant.

Comment: The other day, I downvoted 40 posts like that without needing to know the subject matter. Many of them were later deleted.

Comment: >That's sort of against the StackExchange motto/whatever. - Ok, I see what you mean now. Can you please point me to that 'manifesto'?

Comment: @malenkiy, the network-wide manifesto might be [*We build libraries of high-quality questions and answers, focused on each community's area of expertise*](http://stackexchange.com/about/) and Stack Overflow states [*With your help, we can build good answers to every imaginable programming question together. No matter what programming language you use, or what operating system you call home – better programming is our goal.*](http://stackoverflow.com/about)